# Does NOLOCK still not require the WITH keyword?

Tags: sql-server

We are migrating from SQL Server 2008 and moving to SQL Server 2014. I've searched the Microsoft documentation, but I could have sworn this

```
select * from table (nolock)
```

was going to be an invalid syntax and `WITH` was going to be required.

However, I can't seem to find it in the documentation and I tested it on a 2014 instance without issue.

Ignoring the whole "NOLOCKs is bad" thing, am I totally mis-remembering this or did this change in syntax get removed?

Comment: Even better than updating your code to use proper syntax for query hints would be to eliminate NOLOCK in the first place. It has a whole host of things with it that most people don't understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You remember correctly. The SQL Server 2008 [documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(v=sql.100).aspx):

> Omitting the WITH keyword is a deprecated feature: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

The current (SQL Server 2016) documentation [still says the same thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).

So, yes, this *is* going to be invalid syntax, but Microsoft has not specified *when exactly* this will be the case.

Comment: Figures I would look for the wrong thing. I was thinking it was specific to NOLOCK not the WITH.